# My GUI stopped working?

Tags: unity, c#, gui

Okay I bought this asset online so I would like not to show the whole script. The problem is this asset stopped working when I updated from unity 5.0 to 5.1.2. The script is for a controller GUI interface but it seems to be giving me an error :

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object UnityEngine.UI.Selectable.Select ()

on this line of code :

```
selectedOject.GetComponent<Button> ().Select ();
```

so there is a null reference and its no longer recognizing the child objects as buttons is what I'm assuming

if you want to have a better look at his set up he has a short video On youtube :
[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-4BUeIpIvg)

I would like to continue to use this script and continue updating Unity.

Comment: Is the selectedOject a variable?

Comment: yes its a transfrom

Comment: Are you sure that the name of this variable matches the one on the line and that this variable stores something?

Comment: it does seem to be assigning to the right variable. Its supposedly assigning to the child objects

Comment: Maybe it should be changed to GetComponentInChildren<>().Select();

Comment: nope same thing And i believe the transform is only meant for one object at a time so switching up between the child objects one at a time so its finding the child object and assigning it to that transform

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was way off turns out the problem had nothing to do with the update at all. Apparently I deleted the event system that ran with this. So its working again